# Добавить столбцы в зависимости от количества дней в месяце

Tags: php, javascript, sql

**ТАБЛИЦА НА САЙТЕ**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**КОД  СТРАНИЦЫ**

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['dateList'])) {
    $DATE = new DateTime($_POST['dateList']);
} else {
    $DATE = new DateTime('NOW');
}
$DATE->setTime(23, 59, 59);
$DATE_END = clone $DATE;
$DATE_END->modify('-12 month')->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tab_1` WHERE `user-data` >= '".$DATE_END->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' AND `user-data` < '".$DATE->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'";
$sql = mysqli_query($link , $query);

$DATE_NOW = new DateTime('NOW');
for ($x = 0; $x <= $DATE_NOW->format('t'); $x++) {
    echo $x.' - ';
} 
if ($sql !== FALSE)
{
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo      
            '<tr>'.
            '<td>'.$result['name'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['user-data'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['summa'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>';
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Выполненая работа</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css-style/sql.css">  
</head>
<body>
     <?php include 'connect_tab/connect.php'?>
        <div id="TAB_1">
           <div  style="margin:auto; width:300px; height:100px; 
position:absolute; left:50%;top:9%; margin-left:-80px; ">
                 <legend><b>Введите любую дату</b></legend>
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="date" name="dateList" list="dateList">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
<datalist id="dateList">
<option value="2018-12-08" label="">
<option value="2018-05-15" label="">
<option value="2018-06-15" label="">
</datalist>
</form>
                </div>
            <table border='2' class="all" style="width:1400px;height:400px">
                <caption style=" color:white;font-size:25px;font-weight: bold ;padding-bottom:50px;">ТАБЕЛЬ TECHNOIMPEX</caption>

                <tr>
                    <td style="width:80px"><b>Имя</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>Статус</b></td>
                    <td style="width:100px"><b>Дата</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>Сумма часов</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>1</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>2</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>3</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>4</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>5</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>6</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>7</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>8</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>9</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>10</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>11</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>12</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>13</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>14</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>15</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>16</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>17</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>18</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>19</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>20</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>21</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>22</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>23</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>24</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>25</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>26</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>27</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>28</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>29</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>30</b></td>
                    <td style="width:30px"><b>31</b></td>
                </tr>
                <?php include 'connect_tab/tables_users.php'?>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как можно сделать подобное чтоб после того как в **dateList** я выбрал определенный месяц  и нажал OK у меня построилось определенное количество столбиков (например 30 или 31 или 29) ВМЕСТО ТОГО ЧТОБ КУЧУ НЕНУЖНЫХ СТОЛБЦОВ ВЫВОДИТЬ ПОСЛЕ echo  ?

Comment: Определить сколько дней в месяце и циклом создать нужное количество столбиков.

Comment: Это я понял , я думал найду наглядный пример чтоб от него уже отталкиваться .